# Adding google maps api to Android Studio project causes issue with appcompat

Tags: android, android-studio

The reported issue is the following

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 27.1.1, 26.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1 and com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0

I have tried manually adding the motioned libraries and that solves the error BUT here's the weird part...

While on the **MainActivity.java** file Android Studio continuously shows "updating indices", causing the program to jump up and down...forever.
Doesn't happen on any other file. It happens both before the fix (with red line)and after the fix (no red line).

This is after creating an empty activity project. Has anyone experienced this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure why, but I resolved the issue by not creating a project with AppCompat backward compatibility.

Extending the main class to Actvity rather than AppCompatActivity solved the problem. No issues adding Google apis now.

I'm guessing there is a problem with extending AppCompatActivity and Google apis.